# Does dropbox sdk rest service support proxy setting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, proxy, dropbox, dropbox-api

Does dropbox sdk rest service support proxy setting?
I am using dropbox sdk DBRestClient method – (void)loadMetadata:(NSString*)path; in my own ios application.
I have set up the proxy setting in the Settings app and seems that dropbox sdk doesn’t add the proxy setting on the http request. Is it I need to set in anyway in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from dropbox support - The SDK does not currently offer explicit proxy support.